# Como travar o celular só no aplicativo

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como travar o celular via a código para ficar só no aplicativo, quando apertar voltar e home no aparelho fazer nada, aí apertando um botão ele saia do aplicativo.

Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/android-clicking-twice-the-back-button-to-exit-activity creio que isso pode ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevenir fechar seu aplicativo através do botão de voltar é fácil, basta sobrescrever o método `onBackPressed` da sua **Activity** principal e não disparar o **super**.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // super.onBackPressed(); <- Não utilizar!
}
```

Sobrescrever o botão *Home* acho que é quase impossível da forma que você quer, pois acredito que a única maneira seja fazer um **Launcher**, mas quando o botão é pressionado, o Android pergunta ao usuário qual *launcher* utilizar e dentre eles terá o seu.

Se quiser experimentar esta forma, [aqui](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/) tem um tutorial para isso.